# How to allow multiple cell selection while tracking changes for single cells

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

I am very new to writing VBA-codes and I set up a code to track changes in a basic excel file. Starting with hiding and reopening the track change history sheet when double clicking a cell, then workbook_SheetChange indicating what information I want to track and finishing with Workbook_SheetSelectionChange.

This code works perfectly fine if I only select one cell on the Masterfile sheet. As soon as I select multiple cells, rows and columns or want to copy and paste, I receive a run time error message'13' - Type mismatch. When debugging the code it highlights this part of the code:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    oldValue = Target.Value
    oldAddress = Target.Address
    End Sub
```

As a global variable I have written:
        `Dim oldValue as As String`

I would like to track every cell change, but also allow multiple selection and copy&paste without error message.

Thank you for helping me out and if you need further information, please let me know,
Amy

Comment: I found a solution for this:
       `If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub`
        `If Target.Count = 1 Then`
        `oldValue = Target.Value`
        `End If`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to send multiple cell string values to a single variable (`oldValue`), which is sort of like trying to copy multiple cells into a single cell.

One solution could be to create an array(s), and loop through each cell and treat individually. Here's a sample of one kind of modified to be towards what you're doing:

```
    Dim trackChangesWS As Worksheet
    Set trackChangesWS = Sheet1 'wherever sheet these are being stored.

    Dim MaxArrayCount As Long
    MaxArrayCount = Target.Cells.Count - 1

   'Create Arrays (these could be combined for 1 with two dimensions, 
   'but keeping 2 to match your example)
    ReDim String_Array(0 To MaxArrayCount) As String
    ReDim Address_Array(0 To MaxArrayCount) As String

    Dim rCell As Range
    'loop through cells and capture address and cells
    For Each rCell In Target.Cells
        String_Array(i) = rCell.Value
        Address_Array(i) = rCell.Address
        i = i + 1
    Next rCell

    'set values on some corresponding sheet
    For i = 0 To MaxArrayCount
        trackChangesWS.Range(Address_Array(i)).Value = String_Array(i)
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your feedback @PGCodeRider . As I'm really new to VBA, I'm not sure how to integrate the above into the code I wrote. I fully understand the error I am causing. The aim of tracking the change is: The first sheet is our main database "Variation Masterfile", Team A updates and maintains that information. Every change needs to be tracked on a separate sheet "Tracked Changes" for our Team B to evaluate and have a record of all the changes with a back link. This is what I wrote so far and I assume it's too basic to just include the above Array creation and looping:

```
Dim oldValue As String
Dim oldAddress As String

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sSheetName As String
sSheetName = "Variation Masterfile"
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "Tracked Changes" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("Tracked Changes").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets("Tracked Changes").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Address(0, 0)
Sheets("Tracked Changes").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = oldValue
Sheets("Tracked Changes").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Target.Value
Sheets("Tracked Changes").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Value = Environ("username")
Sheets("Tracked Changes").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Value = Date
Sheets("Tracked Changes").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6).Value = Time

Sheets("Tracked Changes").Columns("A:R").AutoFit
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "Tracked Changes" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("Tracked Changes").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Tracked Changes").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 7), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & sSheetName & "'!" & oldAddress, TextToDisplay:=oldAddress

Sheets("Tracked Changes").Columns("A:R").AutoFit
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

If Target.Value <> "" Then
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
oldValue = Target.Value
oldAddress = Target.Address
End Sub
```